# как привести число к десяти или к сотни или к тысячи?

Tags: c, математика

я что-то не понимаю, но может есть вариант какой то?
допустим есть число `169`. мне надо его разделить на 10%. я его делю.
`169 / 10 == 16`. если это `16` то надо привести число так, чтобы это было `10`. если число получается больше `100` и меньше `1000`, то число должно быть `100`. если число меньше `10000`, то выводить число `1000`.
я попробывал кое что, но это не правильно, даже не хочется выкладывать сюда что я написал.

```
        int sp = curs_high / 10;
        printf ( "sp: %d\n", sp );
        sp = curs_high - sp;
        printf ( "new sp: %d\n", sp );
```

Comment: Т.е. если получается 763, то надо выводить 200? Послушайте, сформулируйте задание нормально, а то ведь без **точного** ТЗ результат будет - ХЗ...

Comment: нет. я немного ошибся. если меньше 1000, то выводить по 100. 200, 300, 400 не надо.

Comment: @Harry всё исправил немного вопрос.

Comment: Извините, я не совсем конкретно понял ваш вопрос, но кажется, что вы что - то не то написали в printf()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо что-то вроде [этого](https://ideone.com/4Da4X3)?

```
pow(10,floor(log10(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

тот ответ который дан, тоже самое что и я сделал вот так.

```
                int sp;
                int nn = 1;
                sp = curs_high / 10;
                while ( sp % 10 != 0 ) {        
                        sp = sp / 10;
                        nn++;
                        if ( sp < 10 ) {
                                sp = 1;
                                break;
                        }

                }
                for ( int i = 0; i < nn; i++ ) {
                        sp *= 10;
                }
```

блин. оказывается я не то хотел что нужно. но если будет меньше тысячи и больше 500, то я хотел по 10 делать, а так было бы много чисел. ладно. спасибо.